# Adding GET HEAD and POST Verbs in IIS Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

I am trying to add three HTTP request filters to my applicationhost.config file using the below:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter 'system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/verbs' -Value @{VERB="GET";allowed="True"} -Name collection
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter 'system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/verbs' -Value @{VERB="HEAD";allowed="True"} -Name collection
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter 'system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/verbs' -Value @{VERB="POST";allowed="True"} -Name collection
```

However, each subsequent line overrides the previous one and I can only add one line it seems. I want to add all three like this:

```
        <verbs allowUnlisted="false">
            <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
            <add verb="HEAD" allowed="true" />
            <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
        </verbs>
```

All I end up with is the first `GET` being written then `HEAD` overriding the `GET` and then `POST` overriding the `GET`...I just want all three listed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `Add-WebConfigurationProperty` instead of `Set-`

Comment: thanks - that worked perfectly...Add-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter 'system.webServer/security/requestFiltering' -Name "verbs" -AtElement @{VERB="GET";allowed="True"}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use the `Set-WebConfigurationProperty` cmdlet, you effectively override the current value of the config section element in question.

If you want to *append* values to multi-valued properties, you should use `Add-WebConfigurationProperty` instead:

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter 'system.webServer/security/requestFiltering' -Value @{VERB="GET";allowed="True"} -Name Verbs -AtIndex 0
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter 'system.webServer/security/requestFiltering' -Value @{VERB="HEAD";allowed="True"} -Name Verbs -AtIndex 1
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter 'system.webServer/security/requestFiltering' -Value @{VERB="POST";allowed="True"} -Name Verbs -AtIndex 2
```

---

If you want to make sure that *only* these three verbs exist in the collection, use `Clear-WebConfiguration` before you add them:

```
Clear-WebConfiguration -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter 'system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/verbs'
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I am using that clear-webconfiguration to check so thanks for the info anyway.